# Azure Databricks Architecture - Communication between Control plane and data plane and authentications

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, aws-databricks

I am trying to understand on Azure Databricks Architecture based on the this [link](https://docs.databricks.com/getting-started/overview.html). I could understand what is the purpose of control plane and data plane in Azure Databricks architecture.But I could't understand on the following questions .

- How control plane and data plane will be communicating?
- How control plane and data plane would be authenticate ?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of communication between control plane & data plane:

1. Legacy - when VMs running on the data plane should have the public IPs, and control plane reaches them directly.  This way was always a security headache.  Azure still supports it & shows in the UI, but it shouldn't be used
2. "No Public IP (NPIP)" or another name "Secure Cluster Connectivity" ([doc and more technical details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/security/secure-cluster-connectivity)).  In this case, when VMs in the data plane are starting, they are opening a bi-directional tunnel to a relay on the control plane, and it's always used for controlling VMs & Spark.  In this setup, VMs don't need public IPs, and it's much more secure & easy to control.

Regarding authentication - it's internal detail, but it provides a way of ensuring that VMs that are communicating with control plane are really that VMs that form a cluster.